# How do I access a Django model attribute within the model class definition?

Tags: python, django, oop

The problem with this code is that when I try to access `self.username` I get a

```
NameError: 'self' is not defined
```

The username attribute is inherited from Django's AbstractUser.

I did some googling and found that I needed to make an init method in order for the self variable to exist. The problem is that I **do not want to do anything in the init** since the rest of my Django code handled the instantiation already and my application is working as is. I tried making an init method with just 'pass' but this also gives me the same error.

Is there any way I can access my attribute without seriously changing the model or making new migrations? I am using Django 2.0 on a Windows 10 OS.

[image: Problematic code]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just avoid the string path concatenation on the upload_to, and move your method out of class

```
def profile_pic_path(instance, filename):
    return 'users/{0}/{1}'.format(instance.username, filename)

class Profile(models.Model):
    #other fields
    profile_picture = models.FileField(upload_to=profile_pic_path)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a callable in the `upload_to` argument to `models.Imagefield`. See the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to).

```
def get_upload_path(instance, _):
    return 'users/' + instance.username + '/'
class Profile(AbstractUser):
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_path, blank=True)
```